# How does Tkinter create an image?

Tags: tkinter

I initialized a picture in the Map class, I don't know why, no display

I want to complete an airplane game,
This requires a Map class and an Airplane class. I want the background image of the Map to coexist with the background image of the Airplane but failed.

Please pay attention to the **init** function in the Map

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

BG_W=852
BG_H=480
BG_C="green"

class Map(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk=Tk()
        self.tk.geometry("852x480")
        self.tk.title("aircraft")
        self.tk.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.cv=Canvas(self.tk, bg=BG_C, height=BG_H, width=BG_W)
        image1=Image.open("material/background.png")
        bg_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
        self.bg=self.cv.create_image(427,240,image=bg_image)
        self.cv.pack()
        # self.tk.mainloop()
        #self.cv.create_image(426, 400,image=ari_image)

    def set_bg(self):
        self.cv.delete(self.bg)
        image1 = Image.open("material/background.png")
        bg_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
        bg=self.cv.create_image(427, 240, image=bg_image)
        self.cv.pack()
        return bg

class Aircraft(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._map=Map()
        image1 = Image.open("material/hero1.png")
        ari_image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
        #===================================================
        image2 = Image.open("material/hero2.png")
        ari_image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
        self.bgs=[ari_image1,ari_image2]
        self.bg_count=len(self.bgs)
        self.now_bg = 0
        self.now_bg_view = self._map.cv.create_image(426,280,image=self.bgs[self.now_bg])

    def start_game(self):
        self.run()
        self._map.tk.mainloop()

    def run(self):
        self.set_bg()
        self._map.cv.after(200,self.run)

    def select_bg(self):
        pass

    def set_bg(self):
        self.del_bg()
        self.now_bg +=1
        if self.now_bg >= self.bg_count:
            self.now_bg=0
        self.now_bg_view=self._map.cv.create_image(426,400,image=self.bgs[self.now_bg])

    def del_bg(self):
        self._map.cv.delete(self.now_bg_view)


def app():
    ari=Aircraft()
    ari.start_game()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

I want the background image of Map to exist at the same time as the background image of Aircraft.

Comment: It looks like you did not keep a reference to the image in your Map class like how you did in your Aircraft class

Comment: Yes, I seem to indicate that this is the problem, but I did not find a suitable solution.

Comment: You say "but failed". Why do you think you failed? What did the program do that is different from what you expect? Does it crash? Does it show the wrong image? Is the image blank?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the program did not crash, but did not display the game background image as expected, only showing the background image of the aircraft.

Answer (score 0):

According to the answers from all of you, I know that the error is because there is no reference to the picture, so I can solve the problem by modifying the following.

```
self.ari_bg1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_ari1)
self.ari_bg2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_ari2)
```

Keep references with self